# Embed QWidget into Other Application

Tags: c++, cocoa, qt

Recently I stumbled upon QMacNativeWidget ([src](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmacextras/source/d96bf490a0342a31343ffc88c34b715675638118%3asrc/macextras/qmacnativewidget.mm#L102) and [header](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmacextras/source/d96bf490a0342a31343ffc88c34b715675638118%3asrc/macextras/qmacnativewidget.h)) which basically makes it possible to use Qt widgets in native Cocoa applications without having to use QApplication.

Now I was wondering whether it is possible to adapt this technique to embed Qt widgets into other GUI kits, say I want to place `QWidget Foo` inside `CoolUIKit Bar`. At a glance this seems pretty straightforward, e.g. the main functionality is to adapt `getEmbeddableView` correctly:

```cpp
NSView *getEmbeddableView(QWindow *qtWindow)
{
    // Make sure the platform window is created
    qtWindow->create();

    // Inform the window that it's a subwindow of a non-Qt window. This must be
    // done after create() because we need to have a QPlatformWindow instance.
    // The corresponding NSWindow will not be shown and can be deleted later.
    extern QPlatformNativeInterface::NativeResourceForIntegrationFunction resolvePlatformFunction(const QByteArray &functionName);
    typedef void (*SetEmbeddedInForeignViewFunction)(QPlatformWindow *window, bool embedded);
    reinterpret_cast<SetEmbeddedInForeignViewFunction>(resolvePlatformFunction("setEmbeddedInForeignView"))(qtWindow->handle(), true);

    // Get the Qt content NSView for the QWindow from the Qt platform plugin
    QPlatformNativeInterface *platformNativeInterface = QGuiApplication::platformNativeInterface();
    NSView *qtView = (NSView *)platformNativeInterface->nativeResourceForWindow("nsview", qtWindow);
    return qtView; // qtView is ready for use.
}
```

**But**: how do I get from `NSView` to `CoolUIKit`? Or is there a completely alternative approach?

Comment: Had another thought about this: since `CoolUIKit` uses native OS X elements, e.g. NSView, this should be manageable via the `NSView` of the corresponding widget.